# iPad landscape only css styles

Tags: css

How can I keep changes to my styles to only effect iPad in landscape?

If I use media queries they also effect desktop if I make the browser smaller.

I've tried placing my queries in :

```
@media only screen and (orientation : landscape) {

}
```

But they still change stuff on my desktop.

Any ideas?

Comment: You really should avoid coding for specific devices (and this is exactly why media queries dont let you target a given device). However, if you must, then you could do user agent detection and import a dedicated stylesheet with these rules in.

Comment: @LDJ yeah, i've really  been trying to avoid doing so however as the height is smaller on iPad some of the content becomes squashed so I was hoping I could target it like this

Comment: as  LDJ says it's not great to target specific devices but that doesn't mean it can't be done you could do a solution like this
@media all and (min-width: 765px) and (max-width: 770px) {
    body{
        background:"xxx";
    }
}
if you for example want one background when the ipad is in standing layout and another when it's in landscape position.

see http://stephen.io/mediaqueries for more info